# How do you use a DAC IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, dac, texas-instruments

I'm attempting to use a DAC0802 chip from Texas Instruments, but I can't figure out why it's not working.

Before anyone asks, yes, I've read [the datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac0800.pdf).

Below I've added a diagram of the voltage on each pin:
[image: Pin Diagram]

Currently, the output voltage is 1.15V, which is weird as I'm expecting 0.
Even weirder, when all the digital inputs are put to 5V, the output is only 1.218V.
Can someone please explain to me why this isn't working? Thanks.

Based on peoples' answers it seems that I've got a current DAC rather than a voltage one. My mistake.

Comment: Please [edit] and post a schematic showing how you have wired up the IC. Without a schematic it would be difficult to know what is wrong.

Comment: We need a schematic of how you've wired up the IC, a layout might also be helpful, also how have you measured the voltage out? What load is across the output pins?

Comment: The circuit does not provide any information how you use the DAC so likely problem is you don't use it correctly, but we don't know how and why you expect those values out of a circuit that is unknown to us. Also the output is not a voltage but a current. So you definitely can't expect it to output voltage between 0V and 5V.

Comment: You've not wired up the "compensation" pin where the datasheet shows a capacitor.

Comment: It's a current-output DAC, not a voltage-output DAC. Check the typical applications circuits starting on page 8.

Comment: @MarkU Yes... I think that's my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You marked pins 1 (V<sub>LC</sub>) and 16 (COMP) as NC (not connected). Yet in every example they are connected (typically to 0 V). V<sub>LC</sub> is used to interface with various logic families by offsetting the threshold voltage (see Figures 10 and 27). At the very least connect it to 0 V.

Additionally, this IC is a **current-output** DAC. You can't simply connect #I<sub>OUT</sub> to 0 V and expect I<sub>OUT</sub> to act as a voltage output. Read the datasheet once again, and especially look at the many application examples.

Comment: Ah... I think I may've made a mistake... Can I use this IC to do voltage output (1 pin equivalent to X volts, 2 pin equivalent to Y volts), or do I need a different chip?

Comment: @SteamRanger Current can be converted to voltage simply with a resistor, but it is unknown if that is what you really want. You can add an op-amp like in the data sheet to have a proper voltage output.

Comment: @SteamRanger I usually wouldn't recommend using a 24 year old part for new designs. You can check the website of the manufacturer of your choice (e.g. [Texas Instruments: DACs](https://www.ti.com/data-converters/dac-circuit/products.html)). If I2C or SPI as interface is acceptable, you'll find some good and inexpensive products.

Comment: @Justme you mean as depicted in Figure 24 for the Op-Amp thing?

Comment: @Velvel Just because something's old doesn't mean it's bad. I still have many M68K CPUs,